# Sum values depending on the header title

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need help with the following :

I have created a table on Sheet1 from A:E with column Titles from A1:E1 The titles are names , under each name there are numbers for example Carlos is the header title Located on A1 and under him there are numbers like 2 on cell A2 3 on cell A4 10 on cell A5

On  Sheet2 I have the names for example from G4:G8 and I want to know the sum of the numbers depending on the name for example next to Carlos on H4 I should be getting 15 which is the sum of the values under his name on the  Sheet1

I have tried vlookup - Index  - HLOOKUP  - conditional combining vlookp or Index but nothing works : (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
=SUM(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$E$6,1,MATCH(G4,Sheet1!$A$1:$E$1)):INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$E$6,4,MATCH(G4,Sheet1!$A$1:$E$1)))
```

Please note that the row index 4 in the second INDEX() as well as the array in the first parameter of both INDEX() have to be changed according to the maximum amount of numbers you expect

Comment: This works fine Thank you Im trying to understand the way you made the formula why did u use ":" ?  also what means the number 1  and 4 on the formula ?

Comment: This is to specify the region for the SUM formula, with hardcoded values it would look like SUM(A1:A5) e.g.
If you do not neet a limit for the number of rows below your name you could try something similar to what @Byron Wall suggests and only use one INDEX formula with the row parameter left empty


=SUM(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$E$6,,MATCH(G4,Sheet1!$A$1:$E$1)))

This would then sum up all rows below the respective name

Comment: In the INDEX function the values 1 and 4 denote the row that is used to obtain the reference from. 
So INDEX(array,1,MATCH(...)) gives me a reference to the cell in the first row (relative to array) and the column retrieved from MATCH. INDEX(array,4,MATCH(...) then gives me the reference to the cell in the same column but the 4th row. SUM(INDEX():INDEX()) then sums up everything between those two references

Answer (score 1):

I assume by "Table" you mean an actual named Table.  In that case you can take advantage of this and use a formula like:

```
=SUM(INDEX(Table1, , MATCH(G4,Table1[#Headers],0)))
```

In my case, my table is named Table1 since it is a default name.

This formula works by searching through the `Table1[#Headers]` for the name in cell `G4`.  It then use that column index to return an entire column using `INDEX`.  Note that there is an empty `rownum` parameter to `INDEX` so it returns the whole column.  From there it takes the `SUM` of this column.

Comment: To be honest with you that will work  but I do not know  how to name a table . How do you name a table to be table 1 ?

Comment: If the Table has already been created, you select a cell in it, go to the Table part of the Ribbon and name it using the text box on the lower left.  If it has not been created, you can use Insert->Table or the CTRL+T shortcut to create it.  Here is a decent tutorial for the whole process http://www.contextures.com/xlExcelTable01.html.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a VBA solution to a worksheet function, this will work:

```
Public Function SumByColumnHeader(name As String, target As String) As Variant

    Application.Volatile
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Set sheet = Application.Caller.Worksheet.Parent.Worksheets(target)

    Dim col As Long
    For col = 1 To sheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        If sheet.Cells(1, col) = name Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next col

    Dim result As Integer
    If col > 0 Then
        Dim row As Long
        For row = 2 To sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            result = result + Val(sheet.Cells(row, col))
        Next row
        SumByColumnHeader = result
    End If

End Function
```

In your cell (for say Carlos in H4):

`=SumByColumnHeader(H4, "Sheet1"`)

Comment: I see the intent of this, but you are asking for trouble using a UDF with no explicit reference to the underlying data (on Sheet1).  This UDF will not update if the data on `Sheet1` changes.  You can get around that with `Application.Volatile` at the top, but I take that as a warning sign if I ever have to use it.

Comment: @ByronWall - Doh!  I was more concerned with simplifying the syntax and completely forgot about that. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

A nice way is to use an array formula. In cell H4 insert the formula:

```
=SUM((Sheet1!$A$1:$E$1=G4)*Sheet1!$A$2:$E$30)
```

Then, instead of pressing the Enter key, press Ctrl+Shift+Enter. What you will see in the formula bar will be:

```
{=SUM((Sheet1!$A$1:$E$1=G4)*Sheet1!$A$2:$E$30)}
```

You can paste the resulting formula to the cells below, as with normal formulas.
I have assumed that your data ends in row 30, but of course you can change this.
A lot of interesting things can be performed using array formulas. Have a look here for a start: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/arrayformulas.aspx